# SwiperJS how to make it possible to swipe on slides with youtube iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, swiper.js

I use iframe from YouTube as slides in SwiperJS. But swipe event doesn't fire on iframe. How is it possible to slide over videos from youtube? Of course, it should be possible to play the videos.
Thanks
Example https://codepen.io/popenkov/pen/WNzLdEq
HTML

```
 <!-- Swiper -->
<body>
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slide-container">
                        <iframe width="500" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a3ICNMQW7Ok?enablejsapi=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slide-container"><iframe width="500" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TZtIGzkcv4M?enablejsapi=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slide-container"><iframe width="500" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a3ICNMQW7Ok?enablejsapi=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slide-container"><iframe width="500" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TZtIGzkcv4M?enablejsapi=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
 var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
            loop: true,
            loopedSlides: 4,
        // function to stop youtube video on slidechange
        on: {
            slideChange: function (el) {
              $('.swiper-slide').each(function () {
                  var youtubePlayer = $(this).find('iframe').get(0);
                  if (youtubePlayer) {
                    youtubePlayer.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
                  }
              });
            },
        },
    });
    var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      touchRatio: 0.2,
      slideToClickedSlide: true,
            loop: true,
            loopedSlides: 4,
        // function to stop youtube video on slidechange
        on: {
            slideChange: function (el) {
              $('.swiper-slide').each(function () {
                  var youtubePlayer = $(this).find('iframe').get(0);
                  if (youtubePlayer) {
                    youtubePlayer.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
                  }
              });
            },
        },
    });
    galleryTop.controller.control = galleryThumbs;
    galleryThumbs.controller.control = galleryTop;
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a CSS overlay, with some space at the bottom for the YouTube controls and a clip-path polygon to match the size of the YouTube button in the middle of the slide. This works if you always use an aspect ratio of 16/9:

```
.video-slide {
    position: relative;
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9; // always use 16/9 video
    container-type: size;

    &:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 14cqh); // show controls
        clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 44% 100%, 44% 49%, 56% 49%, 56% 67%, 0% 67%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%); // show play button
    }
}
```

This allows you to swipe on the slide and still make the video full screen from the controls below. But if you swipe from the button or the button controls swiping will not work.

Answer (score 0):

just update your `.gallery-thumbs` class CSS

```
.gallery-thumbs {
        height: 200px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px 0;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank for your attention. My issue, that I don`t manage to slide main slides with swipe over iframe